# removeClass doesn't work - class isn't removed

Tags: jquery, html, css, navigation, overlay

I am making a mobile menu with a burger-btn that triggers a full width overlay.

This worked but an issue occurred with scrolling of the content behind the overlay. I used this line of code

```
if($('.nav-container').is(':visible')) {
  $('body').addClass("fixedPosition");
} else {
  $('body').removeClass("fixedPosition");
}
```

With this line of CSS so the scroll behind the overlay would be cleared.

```
.fixedPosition {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

The problem is this – when closing the overlay, this class `.fixedPosition`
isn't removed as it should be.

Does anyone have a fix for this?

See my fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/bdL76s59/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to work in my fiddle

```
    if($('.nav-container').is(':visible'))
     {
        $('body').toggleClass("fixedPosition");
     }

});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/bdL76s59/2/

Edit:

Adding `$('body').toggleClass("fixedPosition");` after your code works fine.

Comment: yes it seems to work in my fiddle to.

Do i need this line:
´if($('.nav-container').is(':visible'))
                         {´

?

Could it just be like this, because this also seems to work: https://jsfiddle.net/bdL76s59/4/

Comment: Sorry, my previous comment was wrong, you don't need that anymore :)

Answer (score 0):

It is because your condition execute before your toggle event complete. Try this:

```
 menu.fadeToggle(function(){

                        if($('.nav-container').is(':visible'))
                         {
                            $('body').addClass("fixedPosition");
                         }
                         else
                         {
                            $('body').removeClass("fixedPosition");

                         }
                        });
```

See fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/bdL76s59/3/

Answer (score -1):

`fadeToggle()` takes some time to finish animating opacity.
Until it is not finished `display` property is not toggled from `block` to `none`, but your code checks whether menu is visible right after you started fade animation, so it is still visible. Your else block never run.
To make it work as desired, you have to put your class manipulation code to the `fadeToggle()` complete callback:

```
menu.fadeToggle(function() {
    if($('.nav-container').is(':visible'))
    {
        $('body').addClass("fixedPosition");
    }
    else
    {
        $('body').removeClass("fixedPosition");
    }
});
```